# access wordpress admin setting in php

Tags: php, wordpress

In the wordpress admin you can set "Blog pages show at most" under Settings>Reading

Is it possible to get the value of that to use in my theme? Could I also alter its default setting from my theme pages without going trough the admin? (set it to 20 for example)

Thanks dor your help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're interested in `get_option( 'posts_per_page' );`, which basically tells you what to look for in the `wp_options` table. You can find details [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference).

Also, if you want to change this option, you can do it with [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option).

Answer (score 1):

The option you are looking for is posts_per_page and you get it like:

```
$posts_per_page = get_option("posts_per_page");
```

You could alter the default setting conditionally by using the option filter on your theme page like so:

```
<?php 
    function override_posts_per_page($originalValue){
        if(/* put your page conditional here */)
            return 20;
        else
            return $originalValue;
    }
    add_filter('option_posts_per_page', 'override_posts_per_page', 10, 1);
?>
```